# AWS node.js SDK error - SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Node.js version `0.10.25`

AWS SDK Version `latest - 2.0.23`

I have an app that is continuously listening to a Queue (SQS) and if there are messages posted in that queue the app will read the message and process it and save some data to S3. When I start the app after about 20 minutes I am getting the following error continuously.

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [160] SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20141104T062952Z is now earlier than 20141104T062952Z (20141104T064452Z - 15 min.)
at Request.extractError (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:39:29)
at Request.callListeners (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:18)
at Request.emit (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:604:14)
at Request.transition (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:12)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:606:12)
at Request.callListeners (/myproject/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:104:18)
```

It is not an issue with my system time. My system time is in sync with the time of my EC2 instance. Why am I getting this error? Is it related to SQS or S3?

Comment: i noticed some weirdness recently in the latest node.js sdk where the credentials chain starting looking at the instance profile role ahead of my environment provided credentials and was giving me similar errors.  Have you tried downgrading your package, to say '2.0.10' or so, just to see if it is a recent bug?

Comment: @mattyice - I haven't tried that. Will let you know after doing so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Loren Segal (Amazon) for his quick response. Refer https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/401 for more details. In short, the SDK is not retrying signature errors for which the work around is

```
AWS.events.on('retry', function(resp) {
  if (resp.error.code === 'SignatureDoesNotMatch') {
    resp.error.retryable = true;
  }
});
```

This is not a regression i.e, it is not a bug introduced in `2.0.23`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I experienced it myself today.

Fortunately, and the AWS NodeJS SDK now has this configuration option called `correctClockSkew`, which will fix the system clock offset once an error occurs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#correctClockSkew-property

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Amazon should consider setting the default to true.  Using AWS Javascript SDK in the browser is more common these days, and browser times are unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

## It's likely the time on your computer is incorrect

The signature mismatch is because authentication process depends on clock syncronisation.

Check the time on your machine.

On Linux / WSL you can run `sudo hwclock -s` to fix. Other OSs will require different commands.